# CSS Gradient Opacity Flicker on Hover

Tags: css, sass, styles

I can't figure out why this keeps flickering when i hover over the items. It seems like the opacity gets darker and then lighter when i hover over the sections. It also seems to control the opacity for the other section as well.

I created a codepen so that you guys can see what im talking about. Just hover over the sections.

https://codepen.io/justwil/pen/WNREMgp

```
&:before{
      content:"";
      background: linear-gradient(to right,  rgba(255,76,0,0.60) 0%, rgba(128,34,95,0.75) 100%);
      top:0;
      left:0;
      width:100%;
      height:100%;
      position: absolute;
      z-index:2;
    }
    &:after{
      content:"";
      background-color: rgba(255,206,0,0.65); 
      width:100%; 
      height:100%;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      z-index: 2;
    }
```

Comment: Which browser you're using?

Comment: there is no flickering

Comment: In my case all works great

Comment: It's working fine.

Comment: I'm using chrome. If you hover over the first one you will see the second one get brighter and then darker (flicker). now if you hover off everything and then hover again starting with the second one you will see the flicker on the first one.

Comment: I looked at it in chrome and firefox, I don't see any flickering.  Have you tried another browser? Or maybe restarting? I had some similar flickering after an Nvidia update once. Restarted and it worked fine.

Comment: It seems to be doing what I'd expect of the given CSS - there is some transparency in there and some scaling so it gives the impression of movement and light changing. Could you describe the problem more?

Comment: So, i just tried it on Edge, Firefox and Brave...and it works like it should on Firefox but the other two give me that light changing flicker. The light changing is not what i want (that is the issue)...i just want the background image to zoom in and the title on the left to move in which they do.